# Validar um campo date em javascript para enviar para api no servidor

Tags: javascript, java, vue.js

Galera, bom dia.

Estou com um erro muito chato, estou tentando fazer um put de um formulário em vue.js, porém, quando envio as informações para o servidor que e em java, está quebrando uma exceção de data;

```
[2m[nio-8080-exec-2][0;39m [36m.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Invalid JSON input: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "27-02-2014": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '27-02-2014': Cannot parse date "27-02-2014": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd")); 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "27-02-2014": not a valid representation 
(error: Failed to parse Date value '27-02-2014': 
Cannot parse date "27-02-2014": not compatible with any of standard forms 
("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 22] (through reference chain: ServidorRecadastramentoRequest["dataExpedicaoCTPS"]).
```

Tentei formata os campos na tela das seguintes maneiras:

```
formatDate(value) {
  if (value) {
    return moment(String(value)).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
  }
},

formatDate1(value) {
  if (value){
    return moment("2014-02-27T10:00:00").format('DD-MM-YYYY')
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Na mensagem de erro está a resposta:

```
Cannot parse date "27-02-2014": not compatible with any of standard forms 
("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Seu código está enviando a data no formato `DD-MM-YYYY` mas o servidor espera o formato americano: `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: SIm, eu já tinha percebido o erro, já tentei arrumar dentro do servidor na classe java, e também no service do pagina, estou deixando passar alguma coisa

Comment: Faça um log no javascript para ver se a formatação está sendo feita da forma esperada por você.